# How to match two words that are separate by any variable amount of characters and spaces using regex?

Tags: regex

I am looking to do a regex search that will give me a match of two words with any variable amount of spaces (tab, space, new line etc) or characters in between. For example:

Target: class, constructor

Should match:

```
class myComponent {
  constructor() {
  }
}
```

Should NOT match:

```
class myComponent {
  render() {
  }
}
```

Should also match:

```
class myComponent {
  // imagine a bunch of code here that comes before the constructor
  // with many different lines and many random characters
  constructor() {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can use this regex which matches like you want.

```
\bclass\b(?:(?!\bclass\b)[\w\W])*\bconstructor\b
```

**Explanation for this regex:**

- `\bclass\b` - Matches `class` literally as whole word and not matching partially in a larger text
- `(?:(?!\bclass\b)[\w\W])*` - This matches any input zero or more times in a greedy manner except `class` as whole word, aka [tempered greedy token](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed)
- `\bconstructor\b` - Finally this matches literal `constructor` as whole word

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ctbnnt/2)**